# Overriding CSS from Grails Twitter-Bootstrap Plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a Grails 2.2.1 application that makes use of the Twitter-Bootstrap plugin, which supplies the basic CSS and javascript elements of Bootstrap to Grails applications, along with a tag lib and some other features.

The thing is, I want to use a custom CSS file that offers our company colors, and right now I can only do that by pulling in our own CSS from the app that overrides the elements in the plugin's own bootstrap.css file, meaning that the plugin loads its CSS file first and the app loads its own secondly.  And these files are very big and heavy.

My users, especially those on mobile devices, don't need the burden of an extra 125k of CSS along with the extra processing that comes with doing each rule twice.

Short of building my own custom version of the plugin, is there anything I can do that will prevent the plugin's bootstrap.css file from getting into the web page with my own boostrap.css file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The plugin uses [resources](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BootstrapResources.groovy) to declare the twitter bootstrap files. Luckily resources have a option of overriding definitions of declared modules.

So in your ApplicationResources.groovy, add:

```
modules = {
    overrides {
        'bootstrap-css' {
            resource id: 'bootstrap-css', url:'/css/mycustombootstrap.css'
        }
    } 
}
```